# Printing all ASCII characters between two given characters in C

Tags: c

I have made a program to print out all ASCII character between two given character but then I write it in functions. The output of two these programs are different. I tried using pointer to pass variables by reference but the output is unlikely to be like the first program. What should I do for making it correctly ?

Here is the first program in C by using linear programming.

```
#include <stdio.h>>
int main() 
{
    char a,b,tmp;
    int d;
    scanf("%c%c",&a,&b);
    if(a>b) 
    {
        tmp=a;
        a=b;
        b=tmp;
    }
    d = b - a;
    for (char c = a+1;c<b;c++) 
    {
        printf("%c : %d, %o, %X\n",c,c,c,c);
    }
}
```

Here is the other program in functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>>

void ascii(char a,char b);

int main() 
{
    char a,b,tmp;
    int d;
    printf("Enter 2 character => ");
    scanf("%c%c",&a,&b);
    ascii(&a,&b);
}

void ascii(char a,char b)
{
    int d;
    if (a>b) 
    {
        char tmp= a;
        a=b;
        b=tmp;
    }
    d=b-a;
    for (char c=a+1;c<b;c++) 
    {
         printf("%c : %d, %o, %X\n",c,c,c,c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your function `ascii` is not declared to accept pointers as arguments. And you don't need to (and really shouldn't) pass pointers.

Comment: The phrase "[linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming)" normally refers to something different

Comment: Replace `ascii(&a,&b);` with `ascii(a,b);`

Comment: Variable `d` is irrelevant to the code.

Comment: Please enable compiler warnings, and read the warnings produced. They could have helped you understand this issue, and they will help you to not repeat it.

Answer (score 0):

you should not pass the addresses of your variables to your function the correct one is

```
#include <stdio.h>>

void ascii(char a,char b);

int main() 
{
    char a,b,tmp;
    int d;
    printf("Enter 2 character => ");
    scanf("%c%c",&a,&b);
    ascii(a,b);
}

void ascii(char a,char b)
{
    int d;
    if (a>b) 
    {
        char tmp= a;
        a=b;
        b=tmp;
    }
    d=b-a;
    for (char c=a+1;c<b;c++) 
    {
         printf("%c : %d, %o, %X\n",c,c,c,c);
    }
}
```